# Techniques for solving an equation $f(x)=y^n$ over the integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

Despite of the negative result of Hilbert's tenth problem, diophantine equations of the form $$f(x)=y^n$$ can often be fully solved. Here, $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $n>1$ an integer.

> Is there a systematic way to determine which techniques can be applied ?

I am aware of some techniques like Elliptic curves or hyper-elliptic curves. But I never know which technique can be applied in a concrete case. An example is $$x^2-x+1=y^n$$ which I would like to solve over the positive integers , where $n\ge 2$ is a parameter. This would solve the special case of my question when $$\varphi(n)^2+n$$ is a perfect power. For the primes the expression is $\ p^2-p+1\ $.

$\ x=1\ $ and $\ x=19\ $ are the only solutions upto $10^8$ for every $n$. Any ideas for this special cases ? Any general advices for other functions $f(x)$ ?

Comment: I think there is not. And if you know how to solve some particular cases this is analogous to the fact that you know how to integrate exactly (in closed form) some integrals only (the vast part is not known or has been shown to be impossible).

Comment: I advice you that should mention in the body of the post that $\varphi(m)$ is the Euler's totient function, or well add a explicit reference for your post MSE **3731434** if you consider it.

Comment: @user759001 The main question is about how to approach such equations at all, I only gave an example for further context.

Comment: Just a minor idea, maybe out of personal preference: I'm a bit more used to the form of $y^n-1$ on the rhs, which has some known patterns in its factorization depending on $n$ On the lhs we have then $p(p-1)$ which is also partially factored (and I remember vaguely this relation of $7^3-1$ and $19 \cdot 2 \cdot 3^2$). But likely this is a way too specific detail...